# WebReference vs ServiceReference

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have to following problem. In my application I used a service reference to a non-WCF service from some external company. I created a proxy class using svcutil.exe tool. Everything worked fine for about a year. 
Yesterday however, clients reported that it's not possible to get any response from the service. I figured out that the error returned from the service was:

> The formatter threw an exception while
>   trying to deserialize the message:
>   There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter
>   http://serviceurl:someResponse. The
>   InnerException message was 'There was
>   an error deserializing the object of
>   type specificType

So, what I did I firstly updated the service reference and also generated the new proxy using svcutil.exe. The problem still occurs. 
I resolve the problem by using either 1) wsdl.exe tool to generate proxy class 2) add web reference (which behind the scenes using wsdl.exe tool internally to create proxy). 
My question is : Why everything worked fine for a quite long time even if I used a service reference? How can I checked whether has something changed in the web service? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact the company that provides the web service and find out what changed.